# oracle database import by oradim or impdp

Tags: oracle, import

i am a oracle 11 g user - please tell me, if i have a oracle 11-G database and i shift it on new server ->  if i import this  database on new server by oracle oradim command and if i import this database through oracle impdp utility - which one gives me best performance. also tell me the reason

i have below mentioned IBM SERVER - >
IBM SR650-V2
2 TB X 5 NO. OF SSD - WITH 2.5 GBPS WRITE / 7 GBPS READ SPEED
INTEL XEON - 4314 CPU
RAM - 128 GB

i have imported by oradim command but getting lower perfomance